# Window popup to refresh base file when a text a submited?

Tags: php

In my base page index.php I make use of this

```
<a href="#" onclick="MyWindow=window.open('dialog.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>','MyWindow','width=650,height=600'); return false;" style="color:green;">SHOW</a>
```

to open a dialog window that has a form and allow me to submit some text using PHP.

The `Show` link does not change, you click it, the window opens and may have some data in it.

When I submit something to the dialog.php how can I refresh the index.php?
My goal is to show that data to the index.php

Thank you
UPDATE

I added this to the dialog.php

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

and when I close the window it refreshes the parent page.

Is there a way to make it happen when the

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="ADD">
```

is submited?

Comment: What's on `dialog.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your function, `refreshParent()` to an onclick event for the submit button.

```
<input onclick="refreshParent()" type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="ADD">
```

Note that using 'onclick' tags is generally discouraged. A better way would be to use `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('submit_btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    refreshParent;
}, false);
```

Or with JQuery:

```
$( "#submit_btn" ).click(function() {
    refreshParent;
});
```

Comment: Don't encourage people to use html onclick tags tags, they should be binding event listeners.

Comment: Fair enough, @Jonast92, you are right. I have updated my answer.